# ImageView and swapping images

Tags: android, imageview

I want to create simply application where user can review some pictures. In list I have some pictures and I want to show next pictures after click button. So this is the way: user start application and after click on the button, previous picture is replaced by next picture from the list. I want to use ImageView to show pictures. Can anyone help me?
I tried:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
img.setImageResource(picturelist.get(pictureLeft));
```

where picturelist is list with pictures, and pictureLeft is `int` variable represents my index. To my list I add elements by:

```
picturelist.add(R.drawable.car);
```

Comment: So, what's the problem with your code? What is pictureLeft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like this:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
          if(pictureLeft < picturelist.size())
          {
              img.setImageResource(picturelist.get(pictureLeft));
              pictureLeft++;
          }
     }
});
```